# Summing 2 dynamic cell values

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning HTML and JavaScript. I did a football league table and I was willing to make an automatic system to update the values on that table.
This is the code of the table:

```
<table width="60%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
    <tr class= "promotion_row" style="background:#01DF01;">
        <td id="position">1</td>  <!-- Position -->
        <td id="team" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/malaga.png" width="15" height="15">&nbsp; Malaga CF</td>
        <td id="played">11</td> <!-- Played Matches -->
        <td id="wins">8</td>  <!-- Wins -->
        <td id="draws">1</td>  <!-- Draws -->
        <td id="loses">2</td>  <!-- Loses -->
        <td id="goalsInFavour" value="14" onChange="Count(btn1)">14</td> <!-- Goals in favour -->
        <td id="goalsAgainst" value="6" onChange="Count(btn2)">6</td>  <!-- Goals against -->
        <td id="goalsDifference" value="">8</td>  <!-- Goals Difference -->
        <td id="Points"><b>25</b></td>  <!-- Points -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

And also this script:

```
function Count(btn1, btn2)
{
    var x = btn1.value;
    var y = btn2.value;
    var res = document.getElementById("goalsDifference");

    if(res.value == "")
    {
        res.value = parseInt(btn1.value);
    }

    res.value = parseInt(res.value) - parseInt(y);
}

window.addEventListener("load",Count(btn1, btn2))
```

What I want to do is that it shows the goals difference at start (that's why I added that addEventListener), but it doesn't.
Also, the idea of the function is that it changes dynamically the values in goals difference cell. If I change the goals in favour by summing the goals scored by the team in its last match (I will do that when this is done, also with the goals against), I want the goals in favour to change to the new value and automatically calculate the goals difference and show it on its respective cell.
Is there a way to do so? I will provide more details if needed, maybe I skipped something

Comment: End user cant change <td> text. That's why you shuld use <input> and inputs change event

Comment: if you want without inputing then can take span and call by innerText attribute

Comment: @Esat ARSLAN Thanks a lot .From your Answar I am able to solve Carlos code You gave me the Idia to take the text in the td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoring to your question you perhaps you need to find the difference between two values those are will be taken from the test box in the table .I added two text box and in the keyup event find the dfferent

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "app">
    <table width="60%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
    <tr class= "promotion_row" style="background:#01DF01;">
        <td id="position">1</td>  <!-- Position -->
        <td id="team" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/malaga.png" width="15" height="15">&nbsp; Malaga CF</td>
        <td id="played">11</td> <!-- Played Matches -->
        <td id="wins">8</td>  <!-- Wins -->
        <td id="draws">1</td>  <!-- Draws -->
        <td id="loses">2</td>  <!-- Loses -->
        <td><input type="text" value="14" id="goalsInFavour" onkeyup="return Count();" /></td> <!-- Goals in favour -->
        <td><input type="text" value="10" id="goalsAgainst"  onkeyup="return Count();" /></td>  <!-- Goals against -->
        <td><span id="goalsDifference"></span></td>  <!-- Goals Difference -->
        <td id="Points"><b>25</b></td>  <!-- Points -->
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<script>
    function Count() {
      
        var x = document.getElementById("goalsInFavour").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("goalsAgainst").value;
        var res = document.getElementById("goalsDifference");
        
        res.innerText = parseInt(x) - parseInt(y);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```